# Sending image or video file as response in CakePHP 4 is not working

Tags: php, cakephp, httpresponse, cakephp-4.x

I have tried to send image and video file as response with the code as per CakePHP 4 documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files

Below is my function to access file from url.

```
public function noteFileAccess() {
    $filename = $this->request->getParam('filename');
    $id = $this->request->getParam('id');       
    
    $path = Configure::read('FilePath.NoteFiles');
    $file = new File($path . $id . DS . $filename);
    if(!$file->exists()) {
        throw new ForbiddenException;
    }
    $this->response = $this->response->withFile($file->path);
    //Also tried to set mime type like below commented line
    //$this->response = $this->response->withType($file->mime())->withFile($file->path);
    return $this->response;
}
```

By using above code, it is sending pdf, zip, csv files properly. But images & videos files are not working. Its showing white square in chrome browser. And if downloaded it is showing format not supported in windows system.

Only different I see in downloaded image file vs original image file is image dimensions and some other things like in screenshot below

[image: difference]

Edit: File Content Difference added below

[image]

I have checked with file path & mime type of the image file is good.

Do you think I am missing anything here?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the downloaded file? What's the difference to the original one?

Comment: ps, your code is vulnerable for path traversal attacks, you need to sanitize `$id` and `$filename` or validate the resulting path, otherwise people could easily pass path fragments like `../secret/file`.

Comment: @ndm The function I have added here is just example. I have also user permission validation added in my original code. So only the person can access path who have permission to access that file.

Comment: Hi @ndm I have checked file content difference.. It is also different. I have edited original question to add content difference.

Comment: I was able to fix this now. The problem behind this was the empty line before the start tag of PHP in one of the included file. After checking the difference in content of the original and response file, I got to know that there was empty content included in the response content. Thanks for @ndm for your help.